# Github action to validate yaml files using Yamllint

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I'm adding a github action to validate my yaml files using `yamllint`

By default, when the length of a line surpasses 80 characters, yamllint will output an error like the following one:
`Error: 5:81 [line-length] line too long (101 > 80 characters)`

Is there by any chance a way to override the line-length which is 80 by default?

This can be done on the terminal using this syntax:
`yamllint -d "{extends: relaxed, rules: {line-length: {max: 120}}}" main.yml` but I can't find a way to apply the same thing on my github action.

This is what my github action looks like

```yaml
name: Validate Yaml Files Format

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  validate-yaml:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Yamllint
        uses: karancode/yamllint-github-action@master
        with:
          yamllint_strict: false
          yamllint_comment: true
        env:
          GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Seems like a question you should ask in the Action repo. Those are open source you know? I don’t see any config for it in the repo itself: https://github.com/karancode/yamllint-github-action

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `yamllint_config_datapath` params as described in [the input doc](https://github.com/karancode/yamllint-github-action#inputs) of the github action, as example:

```
      - name: Yamllint
        uses: karancode/yamllint-github-action@master
        with:
          yamllint_strict: false
          yamllint_comment: true
          yamllint_config_datapath: '{extends: relaxed, rules: {line-length: {max: 120}}}'
```